# Converting dataframe to xts object strips hour/minute information

Tags: r, xts

I have a 3x3 dataframe. One of its rows contains Date and Time information. When I convert the dataframe to an xts object, the conversion strips the Time from the data, leaving only the Date behind. I must have the wrong code. Yet, I believe I followed the instructions correctly. Any help would be greatly welcome.

```
library(xts)
library(data.table)

DATSB <- structure(list(DateTime = c("3/28/2016 20:37", "3/28/2016 20:36","3/28/2016 20:35"), Last = c(1221.7, 1221.8, 1221.9), Volume = c(14L,2L, 22L)), .Names = c("DateTime", "Last", "Volume"), row.names = c(NA,3L), class = "data.frame")
setDF(DATSB)
DATSB$DateTime <- strptime(DATSB$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") 
DATSBxts <- as.xts(DATSB[, -1], order.by = as.Date(DATSB$DateTime, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"))


Output for data.frame DATSB:

DateTime               Last Volume
1 2016-03-28 20:37:00 1221.7     14
2 2016-03-28 20:36:00 1221.8      2
3 2016-03-28 20:35:00 1221.9     22


Output for xts object DATSBxts:

            Last Volume
2016-03-28 1221.7     14
2016-03-28 1221.8      2
2016-03-28 1221.9     22
```

Comment: Remove as.Date like this `DATSBxts <- as.xts(DATSB[, -1], order.by = DATSB$DateTime)`. In the future please use `library(xts)` and `library(data.table)` to signal to users what packages you are using that they must load to try your example. We can probably close this as a typo.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. Want to put this as response so I may mark the question as answered?  .... Or better to delete the question as too basic?

Comment: No need. Just add answer and accept. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove as.Date like this `DATSBxts <- as.xts(DATSB[, -1], order.by = DATSB$DateTime)`